# GWT Does Not Load *.nocache.js

Tags: gwt, maven, tomcat7, gwt-maven-plugin

I have this Maven project built with the gwt-maven-archetype. While it runs perfectly with the `mvn gwt:run` goal, however when i try to run it in the tomcat7 container either `mvn tomcat:run` or `mvn gwt:compile && mvn tomcat:run` it does not load the GWT Dynamically created widgets.

According to the Google Chrome console it cannot find the `*.nocache.js` file even though in the `/target/` folder it is exactly where it is expected to be.

I am currently trying to display a simple "Hello" Label in the Entry Point Module :

### GWT Entry Point

```
public class Hello implements EntryPoint {


    public void onModuleLoad() {    
        Label hello = new Label("TESTESTSTSTS");

        RootPanel.get("helloContainer").add(hello);

    }

}
```

### *.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="veltisto.css">
    <title>Web Application Starter Project</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="veltisto/veltisto.nocache.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>
    <noscript>
      <div style="width: 22em; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -11em; color: red; background-color: white; border: 1px solid red; padding: 4px; font-family: sans-serif">
        Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled
        in order for this application to display correctly.
      </div>
    </noscript>
    <div id="helloContainer"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### POM.XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <!-- POM file generated with GWT webAppCreator -->
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>gr.veltisto</groupId>
    <artifactId>web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>GWT Maven Archetype</name>

    <properties>
        <!-- Convenience property to set the GWT version -->
        <gwtVersion>2.4.0</gwtVersion>
        <!-- GWT needs at least java 1.5 -->
        <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <classifier>sources</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.gwtbootstrap</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- Generate compiled stuff in the folder used for developing mode -->
        <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

        <plugins>

            <!-- Copy static web files before executing gwt:run -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                        <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exploded</goal>
                                </goals>
                        </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>             
                    <path>/veltisto</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <!-- GWT Maven Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                                <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                </goals>
                        </execution>
                </executions>
                <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, 
                   see gwt-maven-plugin documentation at codehaus.org -->
                <configuration>
                    <runTarget>veltisto.html</runTarget>
                    <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

### *.GWT.XML

```
<module rename-to='veltisto'>
    <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff. -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.uibinder.UiBinder" />
    <!-- We need the JUnit module in the main module, -->
    <!-- otherwise eclipse complains (Google plugin bug?) -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.junit.JUnit' />

    <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet. You can change -->
    <!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting -->
    <!-- any one of the following lines. -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard' />
    <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
    <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/> -->

    <!-- Other module inherits -->

    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.uibinder.UiBinder" />
    <inherits name="com.github.gwtbootstrap.Bootstrap" />

    <!-- Specify the app entry point class. -->
    <entry-point class='gr.veltisto.web.client.Hello' />

    <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code -->
    <source path='client' />
    <source path='shared' />

</module>
```

Comment: try changing the phase of "maven-war-plugin" from "compile" to "package"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`tomcat7:run` only uses the `src/main/webapp`. You'll want to use `tomcat7:run-war` (which will do a `package`) or `tomcat7:run-war-only` (if you already have a `war:exploded` structure).

Comment: it actually works only with tomcat:run-war. When i specify the goal `tomcat7:run-war` it still does not load the `.nocache.js`

Comment: BTW, the `tomcat:` prefix uses the `org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin` whose latest released is 2 years old. The project has now moved to the Apache Tomcat project and split into `tomcat6-maven-plugin` and `tomcat7-maven-plugin` (which you use), with respective prefixes `tomcat6:` and `tomcat7:` prefix. With `tomcat:run` your `tomcat7-maven-plugin` configuration (`<path>/veltisto</path>`) won't be used.

Comment: And similarly,  `mvn jetty:run-war` fixed this problem for me too.

Answer (score 1):

Using firebug or chrome's inspector, do you see that the `.nocache.js` and `.cache.html` file loaded correctly? Or is there an error like a 404? If there is a 404, look in the path specified by the error in your war directory - is the file there?

If the `.nocache.js` file is missing or in the wrong place, it likely means that the path from the `*.html` page you listed to the compiled JS is wrong.

If the `.cache.html` file is missing, it often means that the gwt:compile was skipped, or that gwt:run or gwt:debug was running during or after the compile. Do not do `gwt:compile` followed by `gwt:run` or `:debug:`, as these latter two will remove the compiled files.

One final thought: The `tomcat:run` phase might be trying to grab a completed `.war` file, and your `war:exploded` will not create one. Additionally, when you run `gwt:compile`, this may not cause a completed compiled war directory to be build. To deal with all of these, consider getting your build working to produce a war file first, and then try to make `tomcat:run` behave. The first step here would be to map `gwt:compile` to the `prepare-package` phase, then make sure that the finished war contains the `.nocache.js` and `.cache.html` files as expected.